# How to create test for control/form (*.designer.cs) to detect error on View Designer (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Given a control/form (*.designer.cs), when opening it on Visual Studio and right click "View Designer", often it won't load with following error message:
"To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:"

[image]

The exact errors aren't relevant because we would like to create failing test for any errors that cannot load "View Designer".

Several solutions that I found but not quite work:

1. Using EnvDTE library
   This option will run Visual Studio and open solution and select *.designer.cs and "View Designer".
   We don't prefer this solution because it requires Visual Studio installed on our test machines.
2. Roslyn 
   Looks promising but by looking inside "View Designer" code i.e. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom, it doesn't seem to use Roslyn at all but instead, it uses the good old CodeDom
3. IVSMDCodeDomProvider/IVsSolution/...
   Visual Studio has several interfaces that seems to able to LoadDesigner without running Visual Studio.
   But unfortunately those interfaces require the project to be 'visual studio package'  or vsix
4. Reverse Engineer Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design to use DesignerSerializationManager/CodeDomSerializer/...
   Seems to be the most likely solution but seems to be tedious work.

The question is any elegant/simpler solution?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/helps.

Comment: The designer won't load for many silly reasons, like when it's not the first class in the file. Sometimes it doesn't load for reasons that resolve themselves that a clean/rebuild doesn't fix, but a restart of VS does. I have a feeling the only solution for this is #1.